# KeyError with pandas in Training Values

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am using a classification model as regression

````
x = base_model.output
x = Dense(1000, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(500, activation='relu')(x) # let's add a fully-connected layer
prediction = Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=prediction)
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics='accuracy') ```
````

my data for X is an image and for Y is an array of 5 element.
now I trained my model and I have this erroe after one epoch training.

```
51/51 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13785.1553 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-ff6c2b8f8c47> in <module>()
      5     callbacks=callbacks,
      6     validation_data=valid_dataloader,
----> 7     validation_steps=len(valid_dataloader),
      8 )

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 557 ``
```

what should I do?
P.N: I use colab for training and this is my colab link:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Mul9PH3m7fvQ8IQNmrRmZMABMwgppp28?usp=sharing

Comment: You should take a look in your data, the problem is an empty key in the row 557 (I guess not sure)

Comment: thank you , yes my problem was from my data